# Karate - Is there a way to match a string with list of strings?

Tags: karate

Response :

```
{
name : 'Sourabh'
}
```

Implemented Validation :

```
And match $.name contains any ['Sourabh','Peter','Babu']
```

The above validation is failing , How can I match a value (Which will be any element from list of values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be more than one way to validate this, I am giving one working example.

```
* def response = {name : 'Sourabh'}
* def expectedList = ['Sourabh','Peter','Babu']
* match response.name == "#string? expectedList.indexOf(_) != -1"
```

Comment: the last line can be simpler `* match expectedList contains response.name`